# Bootstrap Navbar Collapse Button Won't Work in Browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar

Apologies as this has been asked a lot, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. When I resize the window my navbar collapses into a nice button, but if I click on it nothing drops down. Added `js` and `jquery` into `<head>` as most solutions say but still no luck. Any quick solutions? http://codepen.io/chiggory/pen/qNwLWq

HTML:

```
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="size.css" media="screen" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="http://www.thea21campaign.org">A21</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="http://bvhope.blogspot.com">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="learn-more.html">Learn More</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="join-us.html">Calendar of Events</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #800000;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #800000;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #800000;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
  background-color: #800000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

Comment: Geez, thanks much! I'll stop asking stupid questions soon I hope.

Comment: @ErichSterzing Not at all! I observed this issue accidentally. Your questions aren't stupid :) Everyone makes mistakes because of inattention.